# Understanding Cubism.js basics

Tags: cubism.js

What does `context.step(x)` and `context.size(y)` signify ? Does it mean that that the data fetched consists of `y` values in steps of `x` seconds and after every `x` seconds new metric value will be fetched ? Can some please elaborate on this.

Also can we pause `context.step()` until we press some refresh button to reload the metric data? (something like manualRefresh/AutoRefesh toggle button) 
Is there a way to implement this feature?